# disable past dates from given date on datepicker

Tags: javascript, laravel, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to have a date Range selected using the UI date picker.

in the from field people should not be able to view or select dates previous to the given day.

My Code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="from_date" id="f_date"
                       value="{{ Session::get('reviewerJoiningInfo.join_date') ? Session::get('reviewerJoiningInfo.join_date') : null }}"
                       placeholder="From Date" onkeydown="return false" autocomplete="off">
```

getting a date from the session

```
$('#f_date').datepicker({
                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                    var rev_join_date = $('#f_date').val()
                    var reviewer_join_date = $('#reviewer_join_date').val()
                    if(rev_join_date < reviewer_join_date){
                        $('#f_date').val(reviewer_join_date)
                    }
                    $(this).datepicker('hide');
                }
            );
```

I used `minDate: date` but not working.

Comment: [minDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) would be the way to go, you might have used it wrong.

Comment: minDate: '12-10-2021' this is how i used

Comment: datepicker doesn't seem to have a `format` option, use [dateFormat](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

Comment: `format` is working fine in my case.

Comment: I don't use datepicker, but according to the docs, minDate can be "_A string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a relative date._" It might be `minDate` doesn't work in your case because there is no `dateFormat` option

Answer (score 0):

To disable **past year date** you can pass yearrange in parameters.
like

```
yearRange: '1950:2013', // specifying a hard coded year range
```

or

```
   yearRange: "c-100:c+0", // last hundred years and current years
```

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#date").datepicker({
        changeYear:true,
        yearRange: "2005:2015"
    });
});
```

previous 10 years and next 10 years:

```
 $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     minDate: 0,
     yearRange: 'c-10:c+20',

 });
```

if you want to **disable past Date** you can pass startDate or minDate

```
  $('#date').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
     minDate: new Date(),
});
```

**FIDDLE: For disabling past dates**
https://jsfiddle.net/p0deLk56/

Comment: How would disabling years also disable fe. yesterday's date?

Comment: I have a date `12-10-2021` selected in the input field and will disable all past date with year also.

Comment: if you want to disable past Date you can pass startDate or minDate

Comment: i have created a fiddle. link updated in answer

Comment: @brombeer i was just saying if your want to disable past years then you can use year range for past date you can use min date.

Comment: @julker nien akib https://jsfiddle.net/p0deLk56/1/ updated for DMY format

Comment: @Neha I appreciate your answer and thank you.

Comment: I think I am having a version issue but can't figure it out.